# Search for a string and ignore hyphens conditionally

Tags: sql, string, substring, sql-like

keyword: `usedredcars`

I want to list these rows;

```
used-red-cars-florida  
used-redcars-florida  
usedred-cars-florida  
usedredcars-florida
```

EDIT: I want to list all rows includes keyword+dash+% (anything else)

usedredcars-%
and usedredcars can include any dashes

```
u-s-e-d-r-edcars-%  
used-r-e-dcars-%  
usedred-c-a-r-s-%
```

Wit this query,

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE]
where description LIKE keyword+'-%'
```

i get only;

```
usedredcars-florida
```

i dont want this;

```
used-redcarsflorida
usedredcarsflorida
usedred-carsflorida
```

How should i modify my query?

Thanks

More Sample Data;

Keyword: fullstack

fullstack
full-stack
fullstack-academy
full-stack-app's
**fullstackbigdata-com**
full-stack-data
fullstack-dev
full-stack-developer-jobs
fullstack-digital-agency
full-stack-executive
full-stack-fest
full-stack-films
full-stack-finance
fullstack-freelance
fullstack-it-solutions
fullstack-labs
**fullstackmarketing**
full-stack-marketing
fullstack-méxico
full-stack-portfolio
full-stack-pty-ltd
full-stack-resources
fullstack-ro
fullstack-services
full-stack-solutions
**fullstacksolutions.com**
fullstack-staffing
**fullstackstud-io**
fullstack-support
full-stack-technologies
full-stack-toronto

For example here, i want to discard all bold ones

Comment: Remove all `-` before `like`?

Comment: Removing all "-", lists some which i do not want to; forexample: used-redcarsflorida (I dont want this listed) Thanks

Comment: is it always the last '-' you want to keep? does your text always end with 'florida'?

Comment: The dashes may appear anywhere within the keyword to be searched?

Comment: Not allways last. Do not ends allways with "florida" Forexample used-red-cars-downtown-florida @RichBenner

Comment: The dashes can be up to 10 times and anywhere in the description @RobertKock

Comment: I can't see that your request is possible with the criteria given. You cannot include'used-red-cars-downtown-florida ' but *also* exclude 'used-redcarsflorida'. Why don't you want the last one listed? Please clarify what your exact criteria are for including or excluding data. Maybe more examples and reasons why you want/don't want them including would help.

Comment: Looks like we're gonna need regular expressions? What's your DBMS?

Comment: Then you don't have one keyword, you have three. `used` and `red`and `cars`. You would need something similar to `description LIKE 'used%red%cars-%'`. And even that's not robust. You probably need a user defined function that will compare two strings one character at a time, which will be Really slow on a large table. Or, rework your entire data model to actually suit what you're actually using it for.

Comment: What is the maximum number of hyphens you have in your data?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? I see a question, sample input, expected output, attempt to solve.

Comment: Also, as has been asked, what database / RDBMS are you using? SQL Server has different string processing from MySQL, and the others are different too.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2015 @RobertKock

Answer (score 1):

I'm on my phone, so this is pseudo code...

```
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    [table]
  WHERE
        REPLACE('-', '', description) LIKE keyword + '%'
    AND description LIKE REPLACE(keyword, '%-', REPLACE('-', '', description))
```

Will correctly exclude `used-red-carflorida` but won't include `used-red-car-florida-usa`

That's the best I can do in Ansi SQL.

Comment: Just out of interest, would you ever need 'redcarflorida' to match 'used-red-car-florida-usa'?

Answer (score 1):

(This answer assumes you're using SQL Server)

I think you can solve the problem be replacing one `-` at a time and see if you can find an exact match for the keyword:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id int, keyword VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'usedredcars'),
(2, 'used-redcars'),
(3, 'usedred-cars'),
(4, 'used-red-cars'),
(5, 'florida-usedredcars'),
(6, 'usedredcars-florida'),
(7, 'florida-usedredcars-florida'),
(8, 'rarelyused-red-cars'),
(9, 'used-red-carshops');

WITH cte AS (
    -- pad the seed string with hyphens to simplify edge case handling
    SELECT id, keyword, '-' + keyword + '-' AS search
    FROM @t AS base

    UNION ALL

    -- replace hyphens from the middle one at a time
    SELECT id, keyword, STUFF(search, CHARINDEX('-', search, 2), 1, '')
    FROM cte AS prev
    WHERE NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', search, 2), LEN(search)) > 0

    -- BE ADVISED that STUFF can return unexpected size varchar and thus:
    -- Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part
    -- explicitly cast the result to desired size if that happens
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE search LIKE '%-usedredcars-%'
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee0e74b02a030746a4e502fb05fa4273)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify your DBMS, I consider it Oracle.
It's not a very elegant solution but it should work:

First create a function that converts the keyword into a regular expression:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION keyword2re
(
  p_kw IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  v_result VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_length INTEGER;
  v_count  INTEGER;
BEGIN

  v_length := LENGTH(p_kw);
  FOR v_count IN 1..v_length LOOP
    v_result := v_result || '[\-]*' || SUBSTR(p_kw, v_count, 1);
  END LOOP;
  v_result := v_result || '([\-].*)?$';
  RETURN v_result;

END keyword2re;
```

It preceeds every character with optional dashes and says an eventual remaining part should start with a dash.

So

```
used
```

becomes

```
[\-]*u[\-]*s[\-]*e[\-]*d([\-].*)?$
```

After that execute the query

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(description, keyword2re('fullstack'));
```